# EF Core Migrations not being recognized

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

after I execute the add-migration in the PMC the migration class is created with all the correct changes need in the Up method.

When I run the update-database command in the PMC I get the error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The migration '***MigrationName***' was not found.
```

I have never seen this before and the file it says is not there clearly exist.

If I execute the remove-migrations command the newly created migration class is not removed, I get an error stating that the previous migration has already been applied.

It appears that all new migrations created with add-migrations are not recognized via the update-database or remove-migration commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reasons for this is that dbcontext is not in startup project and it is inside another project. In this case PM may not be able to find routes to complete migrations. We can use dotnet with explicit dbcontext and proj name where dbcontext is:

dotnet ef database update --context YourAppContext --project YourProj

Comment: That was the answer when I solved the issue.  If I remember the situation correctly.  I moved all the EF6 to EF Core which was created in a new project.  I was trying to create the migrations from the original EF6 startup project.

Answer (score -1):

We just had the same issue. The problem was that, we excluded the *Migrations* folder from the solution in *Visual Studio*.

- <kbd>Project</kbd> ⇒ <kbd>Show all files</kbd>
- <kbd>Right Click</kbd> on "*Migrations*"
    » <kbd>Include in project</kbd>

The above steps resolved it for us.

Comment: What my problem was that I have multiple executable projects.  So when I 1st was running the migrations.  I was MyExample.Console as the startup project.  I then added another MyExample.Core.Console Project and that was the startup project.  Because the migrations were ran initially under the MyExample.Console project, that project file had all the file listing for the migrations.  The new MyExample.Core.Console, that project file didnt know anything about those migrations so it was never able to find them.